# Rails - When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5 app, I have this error:

when I use this table to list the tags of a related object (in this case an Annotation)

```
<tbody>
        <% object.tags.each do |tag| %>
            <% unless tag.content.blank? %>
            <tr>
                <td style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="displaytagedit"><%= link_to tag.content, **[object, tag]**, method: :patch %></td>
```

It tries to open this link

`http://localhost:3000/annotations/6/tags/24` (which appears correct)

and throws this error:

> When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

On this part of my controller (below)

```
tagable = detect_tagable
@tag = tagable.tags.update(params[:id])
@tags = Tag.all
render '_tag_update'
```

end

It should call this form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @tag, html: { class: 'form-vertical', multipart: true },
    wrapper: :horizontal_form,
    wrapper_mappings: {
    check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
    radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
    file: :horizontal_file_input,
    boolean: :horizontal_boolean
    } do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :content, placeholder: 'Tagged content', label: false %>
    <%= f.association :tagtype, prompt: 'Select tag type', label: false, :collection => Tagtype.active.order(:name).where(:documenttype => object.documenttype_id) %>
    <%= f.input :location, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => 'x=0, y=0' }, label: false %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end -%>
```

Tags are a reusable model on (for now) 2 objects.

This is the routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'dashboard#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, :documenttypes, :tagtypes, :business_partners

  resources :documents do
    resources :comments, :tags
    get "pdf", on: :member 

  end

  resources :annotations do
    resources :comments, :tags
    get "pdf", on: :member

end
```

### Update

this is the tag controller:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

def create
    tagable = detect_tagable
    tagable.tags.create(tag_params)
    redirect_to tagable_path(tagable)
end

def update
   tagable = detect_tagable
   @tag = tagable.tags.find(params[:id])
   @tags = Tag.all
   render '_tag_update'
end

def destroy
   tagable = detect_tagable
   @tag = tagable.tags.find(params[:id])
   @tag.destroy
   redirect_to tagable_path(tagable)
end

  private

    def tagable_path(tagable)
      case tagable
      when Document
        document_path(tagable)
      when Annotation
        annotate_path(tagable)
      else
        fail 'Unknown tagable'
      end
    end

    def detect_tagable
      if params[:annotation_id]
        Annotation.find(params[:annotation_id])
      elsif params[:document_id]
        Document.find(params[:document_id])
      else
        fail 'Tagable not found'
      end
    end

    def tag_params
      params.require(:tag).permit(:content, :location, :tagtype_id, annotation_attributes: { annotation_ids:[] }, document_attributes: { document_ids:[] })
    end

end
```

Where is my error/mistake?

Comment: `@object`, not `object` (having that you have define it)

Comment: looks like that takes me to the annotation in this case; I need to get to edit the tag.

Comment: what is `object` for? there is no `object` object defined. What you have access to in view is instance variable (with `@`) defined in controller or (logically) in view. You did define `@tag` variable in controller (even though I am not sure which action does this view correspond) - so in view you have access to `@tag` If this is index action's view, you should create index action in controller saying `def index @tags = Tag.all end` then you can use `@tags` variable in view.

Comment: this is not index view; the table is a partial that lists all the tags for the related object (polymorphic). so here object can be "document" or "annotation" to which the tag belongs. Much like comments to a blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show us your controller? probably it's a typo in `object` which really would be `@object` as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044491/undefined-local-variable-or-method-object#comment67364990_40044491) says

Anyway, send your controller code to confirm this

### EDIT:

In your TagsController file you must set the update method like this:

```
def update
  tagable = detect_tagable
  @tag = tagable.tags.find(params[:id])
  @tags = Tag.all #Or whatever query you want if you want to select more specific Tags
  render '_tag_update'
end
```

Comment: added the controller

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter Probably is `@tags` and not `object.tags`. Can you tell us to which controller method corresponds the views that you posted?

Comment: Okey, so [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044491/undefined-local-variable-or-method-object/40044698?noredirect=1#comment67365672_40044491) is right, you must set @tags in the update method. I will edit my answer to explain me better

Comment: OK, done - now if I get error on the form: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty when i use `<%= render tags/tags_update, :object => @tag %>` or a routing error when using `<%= link_to tag.content, @tag, method: :patch %>`

Comment: This starts to be confusing, please do other post talking about this new errors, or edit your question adding more details, be the most specific you can. which lines throw your errors? the render method? or the form partial? What do you say with routing error? it fails or it brings you to wrong page?

Comment: I updated the posting; thanks for helping out (it is my first app to learn rails).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125722/discussion-between-hugo-farji-and-dimitri-de-ruiter).